Spring Boot 3.2.5 RestClient POST with form args
I'm using Spring Boot 3.2.5 and the new RestClient class to call a POST the requires url encoded form arguments.  I'm sending a Map as the body and it keeps trying to convert to JSON which is not what the API requires.  Are there any good examples of using the RestClient in this capacity?
    RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder()
        .defaultHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .build();

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restClient.post()
        .uri(fedExURL + tokenUri)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
        .body(body)
        .retrieve()
        .toEntity(String.class);


